# how can I filter an array without losing the index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have two really long arrays containing "picture names" and "picture files". The first one represents the actual name of the pictures, while the second one is just the file name. For example:

```
picturenames[0] = '0 - zero';
picturenames[1] = '1 - one';
picturenames[2] = '1 o\'clock';
...
picturefiles[0] = 'numbers-zero.jpg';
picturefiles[1] = 'numbers-one.jpg';
picturefiles[2] = 'time-1.jpg';
...
```

I have about 1000 items in each array in several languages (the picture files are always the same). I'm "recycling" these arrays from the previous application to save some time and avoid rewriting everything anew.

**Desirable functionality**: using the user's input in a textbox I want to filter the `picturenames` array and then show the correspondant `picturefiles` image.

**The issue I'm facing**: when I filter the `picturenames` array I lose the index and I can't "reach" the picture file name.

This is the code I'm using to filter the `picturenames` array.

```
var matches = picturenames.filter(function(windowValue){
    if(windowValue) {
        return windowValue.indexOf(textToFindLower) >= 0;
    }
});
```

What would be the best way to do this?

**UPDATE**: the solution proposed by Ahmed is the best one, but for time reasons and negligible performance issues I'm just using a for loop to search trough the array, as follows:

```
        var matchesCounter = new Array();

        for (i = 0; i < picturenames.length; i++) {
            if (picturenames[i].indexOf(textToFindLower) >= 0) {
                matchesCounter.push(i);
            }
        }

        console.log(matchesCounter);

        for (i = 0; i < matchesCounter.length; i++) {
            console.log(picturenames[i]);
            console.log(picturefiles[i]);
        }
```

Comment: why wouldn't you just have them as an object instead?

Comment: I would rather not rewrite all the vocabulary: we are talking about 1000 items for the pictures and around 350 items for the audio files, in 7 languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one property `index` during the filtering time, then later on you can use the `index`.

```
var matches = picturenames.filter(function(windowValue, index){

if(windowValue) {
    windowValue.index = index;
    return windowValue.comparator(textToFindLower) >= 0;// Need to define comparator function
}
});
```

Later on you can access by using like follows:

```
picturefiles[matches[0].index]
```

However, the solution will work on object, not primitive type string.

If your data type is string, then you have to convert as object and put the string as a property value like `name`. The snippet is given below:

```js
var picturenames = [];
var picturefiles = [];

picturenames.push({name:'0 - zero'});
picturenames.push({name:'1 - one'});
picturenames.push({name:'1 o\'clock'});

picturefiles.push({name:'numbers-zero.jpg'});
picturefiles.push({name:'numbers-one.jpg'});
picturefiles.push({name: 'time-1.jpg'});

var textToFindLower = "0";

var matches = picturenames.filter(function(windowValue, index){

if(windowValue) {
    windowValue.index = index;
    return windowValue.name.indexOf(textToFindLower) >= 0;
}
});

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I must be doing something wrong: when I try to use console.log(matches[0].index); I get "undefined" after having some actual matches on my search. I will add more information to the main question.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately changing the arrays it's going to be painful even using "replace text". What if I use a for loop? I'm going to try and see what's the performance like...

Comment: Using another loop have some performance penalty, however for 1000 items its negligible. and it will add more o(n) complexity. To avoid this you can create your own comparator function, where you can keep the index of matched item to reduce the complexity.

Comment: I just made a test and It works pretty well. I'll mark your answer as the solution since it's the most appropriate way to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
const foundIndicies = Object.keys(picturenames).filter(pictureName => {
  pictureName.includes(textToFindLower)
});
// reference picturefiles[foundIndicies[0]] to get the file name
```

Though, it would be far nicer to have both the name and the file in a single object, like so:

```js
const pictures = [
  {
    name: '0 - zero',
    file: 'numbers-zero.jpg',
  },
  {
    name: '1 - one',
    file: 'numbers-one.jpg',
  }
];

const foundPictures = pictures.filter(picture => picture.name.includes('zero'));
if (foundPictures[0]) console.log(foundPictures[0].file);
```

Comment: there can be multiple matches, for example: search for "dog" --> ["dog", "dog", "doghouse", "hot dog", "hotdog", "pet the dog", "walk the dog"]

Comment: Edited - then you just need to do `Object.keys(picturenames).filter`